# Suggest field not found though it's indexed

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I'm trying to do autocomplete with ElasticSearch. Currently I have a field mapped for it called **suggest**. I have the following query:

```
POST dev/facility/_search
{
  "suggest": {
        "song-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "faci", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" :"suggest" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I"m getting this error: `no mapping found for field [suggest]`. My mapping can be seen here:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "mappings": {
      "facility": {
        "properties": {
          "slug": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "state": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "suggest": {
            "properties": {
              "input": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've used NEST to generate my mapping and this is my annotation on the field:

```
    [Completion]
    public CompletionField Suggest { get; set;
```

Comment: Your mapping shows that the `suggest` field is not of type `completion`. So probably your index and the `suggest` text field already existed prior to changing its type to `completion`. You need to delete your index and repopulate it in order for the `suggest` field to be properly mapped.

Comment: @Val I deleted the index and index the document again...same issue and the mapping comes back as the same type.

Comment: Which version of NEST and which version of ES are you running?

Comment: @Val ES: 6.2 and NEST 6.1.0

Comment: @Val my apologies...it's NEST 6.1.0

Comment: Well, there's obviously something wrong in your mapping code. If you care to share it...

Comment: Ensure that you call `.AutoMap()` to have NEST apply any mapping attributes when creating the mapping: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html